# Storing json data into pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here I am defining my pandas DF

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ColA',
                       'ColB',
                       'ColC',
                       'ColD'
                          ]
```

Then making a rest request for json response with the data I want

```
..building json requst
js = request.json()
return_list = js["result"]["data"] #json list
```

Then I am using this to add that data to my dataframe

```
#loop through returned data
for id in return_list :
    line = []
    #looping through all elements for each data point
    for x in return_list[id]:
        line.append(torrents[id][x])
    df.loc[df.size] = line
```

However, that final block of code is being very slow.. how can I optimize it?

Here's an example of what I could do if this worked

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a',
                       'b',
                       'c',
                       'd'
              ])

x = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
df.append(x, ignore_index=True)
#however, df will be empty
```

Comment: `df.append(line)` any faster? But if you already have all the data, then build the whole 2D array first and create the dataframe as `df = pd.DataFrame(data_array, columns=...)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang I making tons of rest requests, paging each time so the data is coming incrementally.

Comment: Still, pandas' DataFrame are not designed for repeatedly adding one row at a time. can you cache your data and append them by chunk?

Comment: @QuangHoang I added a test case to my original post, if that test case could work, I could bulk add as you suggested, but pandas append doesn't like a list of lists